# Wordpress WebPage not giving a correct responsiveness on different devices

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I created a website using WordPress, and it works completely fine on computer browser. Whereas on tablet its responsiveness is not working fine as the contents are slightly shifted towards left side.
[Page displayed on PC in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mshzi.jpg)

But on tablet I have issues and its displayed in a strange format.

[Page displayed on IPAD in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSjfZ.jpg)

Comment: in order to avoid shifting of page towards left (on mobile and tablet devices) I modified my style.css file, and added margin: 15px;
#content {
 clear: both;
        margin: 15px;
 padding: 30px 10px;
}                       But I do not think its the right way to do it.